# Sitecore 8: how to track Content Editors activity?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

We have a website featuring Sitecore 8.1 with multiple content editors. Is there any way to log their activity, as in listing the actions they have performed in terms of editing/publishing/unpublishing?

We had a problem last week which I suspect being caused by someone unpublishing the wrong item, but I need to make sure this is the case, or at least I would like this ability in the future.
Do I need to create my own event-triggered logging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing fully out of the box to provide those reports in Sitecore. You can take a look at the [Sitecore Audit Trail](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_Audit_Trail.aspx) module which will log all the "editor action" audit information into a separate log4net appender. You can find more information on the module in [this blog post](http://klpatil.github.io/Sitecore-Audit-Trail/), but note that the module is only mark as compatible to Sitecore 7.5, it should not be hard to make this work with Sitecore 8.1, namely updating the appender config since the `log4net` config is now within the `<sitecore>` node in config.

Answer (score 3):

Sitecore does log content editor actions out of the box in the normal log files (in Data\logs), they start with "AUDIT" so you can find them. It logs things such as items being saved, publishes starting, etc. Do a search in the log files to find them.

You can get these saved to a separate log file for easier review: https://sdn.sitecore.net/scrapbook/how%20to%20make%20sitecore%206%20write%20audit%20log%20to%20its%20own%20file.aspx

This still works in Sitecore 8 except the setting is in App_Config/Sitecore.config now.

Comment: Thanks for contributing to my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sitecore Advanced System Reporter

Sitecore 6 ships with a very useful function called My Locked Items. At times, though, admin users may want to see all locked items, not just those locked by them. I wrote a little application to do just that. Then I thought of making it more generic, so that one could create other type of reports easily. The result is a little framework which allows to create many types of reports in very short time. In this module I provide this framework together with many useful example reports like:

```
items modified updated in the last X days
items that have more than X children
items that are publishable but either do not exist or have a different version in the web   
   database.
items that are based on a particular template
items with validation errors
which templates have been linked to a workflow
locked items
publishable items with broken links
audit information
errors in the log files
items that have stayed in the same workflow state for more than X days
```

and more.

You can now also parametrise those reports, save them as links in the desktop, export them, or even create a scheduled task that emails some of them automatically. In addition, you can also apply commands to the items reported.
You can download the module from :  https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/A/Advanced_System_Reporter.aspx

Module is available for Sitecore 6.4 to 8. I don't know if has the functionality you look but you can customize it.

You can check this blogpost how to extend it: http://www.seanholmesby.com/sitecore-auditing-with-the-advanced-system-reporter/

**Update**

Install the module

Run the module and choose reports like in picture.

[image]

Run the report

[image]

View the report or export it like csv, excel or xml .